# confused about @ModelAttribute annotation in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I have used the `@ModelAttribute` annotation on a `get` method in my controller:

```
@ModelAttribute
public TSetTestEmp get(@RequestParam(required=false) String id) {
    TSetTestEmp entity = null;
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(id)){
        entity = tSetTestEmpService.get(id);
    }
    if (entity == null){
        entity = new TSetTestEmp();
    }
    return entity;
}
```

and have requested the `TSetTestEmp` info like this:

```
@RequiresPermissions("set:emp:tSetTestEmp:list")
@RequestMapping(value = {"list", ""})
public String list(TSetTestEmp tSetTestEmp, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
    Page<TSetTestEmp> page = tSetTestEmpService.findPage(new Page<TSetTestEmp>(request, response), tSetTestEmp); 
    // model.addAttribute("tSetTestEmp", tSetTestEmp); // fixed using this.
    model.addAttribute("page", page);
    return "modules/set/emp/tSetTestEmpList";
}
```

As beginning without the comment statement, the JSP code like below throw an exception:

```
<form:form id="searchForm" modelAttribute="tSetTestEmp" action="${ctx}/set/emp/tSetTestEmp/" method="post" class="form-inline">
    <span>Employee Name：</span>
    <form:input path="empName" htmlEscape="false" maxlength="64"  class=" form-control input-sm"/>
</form:form>
```

Error

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'tSetTestEmp' available as request attribute
```

According to my debugging, the `form:input` tag causes this exception. If I use `input` tag and bind the value `empName` using `${tSetTestEmp.empName}`, this page will show the right result.

If I want to use the `form:input` tag in my JSP page, the comment in the list method must be removed which means I must assign the Model manually.

@M. Deinum suggested me to fix the problem like this and it works:

```
@RequiresPermissions("set:emp:tSetTestEmp:list")
@RequestMapping(value = {"list", ""})
public String list(@ModelAttribute("tSetTestEmp") TSetTestEmp tSetTestEmp, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
    Page<TSetTestEmp> page = tSetTestEmpService.findPage(new Page<TSetTestEmp>(request, response), tSetTestEmp); 
    model.addAttribute("page", page);
    return "modules/set/emp/tSetTestEmpList";
}
```

But as I can see, the initial code without `@ModelAttribute` before method  argument can also reach the instance returned by `get` method. However the JSP page just cannot reach it same as back-end do.

I'm totally confused about how this situation happens.

Thanks for reading till here :)

Any suggestion will help.

Comment: Add `@ModelAttribute` on the method argument as well.

Comment: @M.Deinum It works. I comment the addAttribute statement and add `@ModelAttribute` before the argument named tSetTestEmp in list method. Does it mean a method annotation and a method argument annotation combining together will match the form:input on the front-end ? What's the principle？How did I get this exception？

Comment: it was also not fixed by the `addAttribute` as that was a completely different instance as the one created in the `get` method. With `@ModelAttribute` on the method argument you tell spring mvc that you want to have that object available in the model, now as you are again doing setup of the model one overrides the other and if you don't put `@ModelAttribute` on it it will effectilvy negate the effect of the `@ModelAttribtue` method.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I understand what you just say, but the point is the argument `tSetTestEmp` in the `list` method has got the instance initialized by `get` method successfully. When coming to the JSP page, the exception occurs. I think that means my back-end just goes well, something must be wrong in the front-end or the configuration.@M.Deinum

Comment: No there is nothing wrong, please read my comment... Having a `@ModelAttribute` on the method argument is important without it a new fresh instance will be created. Also do you really access the jsp by the controller or directly! Next to that your `list` method is called always, so on a post you loose some parts. And as I explained in my comment, because you don't have a `@ModelAttribute` and explicitly set stuff into the `Model` that takes precedence over earlier configured implicit `Model`s.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have said that because I have another page just goes well with the initial code :( and of course I access it by the controller through the `@RequestMapping` annotation.

Comment: I highly doubt that that code is *exactly* the same. Or the code isn't what you have posted here.